# OnClick change image src from Json array JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

I have a JSON array which contains some objects with image arrays and some with a single image .. example :

```
[  
   {
     "title": "Title",
     "img_src": "example.png"  
     },
   {
     "title": "Title2",
     "img_count": 2,
     "img_src": [
       "example2.png",
       "example3.png"
     ]  
   },
   {
     "title": "Title3",
     "img_src": "example4.png"  
     },
   {
     "title": "Title4",
     "img_count": 3,
     "img_src": [
       "example5.png",
       "example6.png",
       "example7.png"
     ]  
   }
]
```

Now, I'm showing the image in between two buttons, how can I change the image of a particular object (retrieved from JSON) through these buttons?

This is what I've done :

```
export default function Products({ jsonArr }) {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);

  function toggleImage(index) {
      setCounter(counter === 0 ? 1 : 0); //This is just for testing.
  }

.........
........

<div className="parentElement">
              {jsonArr.map((arrEl, i, _) => {
                return (
                  <div key={`${i}`} className="row" style={{ marginBottom: "50px" }}>
                    <div className="col-sm-4">
                      {arrEl.img_count && (
                        <button onClick={() => toggleImage(i)}>
                          <iconify-icon icon="ep:arrow-left-bold"></iconify-icon>
                        </button>
                      )}

                      {arrEl.img_count ? (
                        <img key={arrEl.title} src={arrEl.img_src[counter]} className="cover" height="250" width="250" alt="products"></img>
                      ) : (
                        <img key={arrEl.title} src={arrEl.img_src} className="cover" height="250" width="250" alt="products"></img>
                      )}
                      {arrEl.img_count && (
                        <button onClick={() => toggleImage(i)}>
                          <iconify-icon icon="ep:arrow-right-bold"></iconify-icon>
                        </button>
                      )}
                    </div>
...more code here...
```

I'm showing the buttons only when 'img_count' is present in an object. The 'toggleImage' button functionality is working but it's changing the images of all the objects of an array.

Please suggest some better approach to do this. Or if this can be corrected.

Comment: It seems you need a separate `counter` for each thing in jsonArr.  Perhaps use a separate component for each element of jsonArr, with its own counter state var.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently the code has only the one single `counter` state that ***every*** mapped `jsonArr` array object is referencing, so they all change/update at the same time.

If you would like each mapped element to have its own state then abstract the JSX into a React component and move the `counter` state to each one.

Example:

```
const MyComponent = ({ data }) => {
  const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);

  const nextImage = () => {
    setIndex(index => index + 1);
  };

  const prevImage = () => {
    setIndex(index => index - 1);
  };

  return (
    <div className="row" style={{ marginBottom: "50px" }}>
      <div className="col-sm-4">
        {data.img_count && (
          <button onClick={prevImage}>
            <iconify-icon icon="ep:arrow-left-bold" />
          </button>
        )}

        <img
          key={data.title}
          src={data.img_count
            ? data.img_src[index % data.img_src.length]
            : data.img_src
          }
          className="cover"
          height="250"
          width="250"
          alt="products"
        />

        {data.img_count && (
          <button onClick={nextImage}>
            <iconify-icon icon="ep:arrow-right-bold" />
          </button>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```
<div className="parentElement">
  {jsonArr.map((arrEl, i) => (
    <MyComponent key={i} data={arrEl} />
  )}
</div>
```